# How one can do PCA and visualize it all inside LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Say I have 3 vectors:

```
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}

    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    4 \\
    5 \\
    \end{pmatrix}

    \begin{pmatrix}
    3 \\
    4 \\
    7 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
```

I want to draw a 2d PCA of them in TikZ/PGF, is it possible without exiting latex (via some package) or one must compute PCA outside and only feed data to TikZ/pgf?

Comment: @marmot I guess he is referring to principal component analysis. While calculations are possible in LaTeX I'd advice you to not do them with it (especially for matrix operation heavy tasks). You could just use python and its `matplotlib` using the pgf back end of it.

Comment: I do believe that you could do that with Ti*k*Z but I do not fully understand the question. What you could do with Ti*k*Z is to install 3d-type coordinate systems and the corresponding transformations. However, I do not understand the question. Don't you need some additional vectors that you are going to subject to the transformations to get an output?

Comment: Why you use `$$...$$` instead of `\[...\]`?

Comment: If you really want to do this you'd have to implement an algorithm which can calculate the covariance matrix (rather easy), and the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of that matrix (this seems a bit harder in TeX). And if you want to do that, I'd advice you to use `l3fp` (part of `expl3`) for the floating point precision. Of course this is all possible, but it'd take some time (writing and computing) compared to do it in some other languages (e.g. like Python). And if you do it in some other languages you can write a neat Makefile that runs Python if necessary to recalculate the values.

Comment: (that's what I did back when I gave a presentation about PCA, all the calculations were done by Python)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is the answer you are looking for. To me judging from [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) it seems that all you need to do is to be able to invert general coordinate transformations. And this is what the following code does.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\def\myparse(#1,#2,#3){\xdef\myx{#1}\xdef\myy{#2}\xdef\myz{#3}}
\tikzset{define x/.code={\myparse#1%
\xdef\globxx{\myx}%
\xdef\globxy{\myy}%
\xdef\globxz{\myz}},
define y/.code={\myparse#1%
\xdef\globyx{\myx}%
\xdef\globyy{\myy}%
\xdef\globyz{\myz}},
define z/.code={\myparse#1%
\xdef\globzx{\myx}%
\xdef\globzy{\myy}%
\xdef\globzz{\myz}},
install trafo/.code={\tikzset{x={(\globxx,\globxy,\globxz)},%
y={(\globyx,\globyy,\globyz)},z={(\globzx,\globzy,\globzz)}}},
install inverse trafo/.code={%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mydet}{\globxx*(\globzz*\globyy-\globzy*\globyz)
- \globyx*(\globzz*\globxy-\globzy*\globxz)
+ \globzx*(\globyz*\globxy-\globyy*\globxz)}
%\typeout{det=\mydet}        
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myxx}{(\globzz*\globyy-\globzy*\globyz)/\mydet}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myxy}{-(\globzz*\globyx-\globzx*\globyz)/\mydet}   
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myxz}{(\globzy*\globyx-\globzx*\globyy)/\mydet}
\tikzset{x={(\myxx,\myxy,\myxz)}}  
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myyx}{-(\globzz*\globxy-\globzy*\globxz)/\mydet}  
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myyy}{(\globzz*\globxx-\globzx*\globxz)/\mydet}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myyz}{-(\globzy*\globxx-\globzx*\globxy)/\mydet}   
\tikzset{y={(\myyx,\myyy,\myyz)}}  
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myzx}{(\globyz*\globxy-\globyy*\globxz)/\mydet} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myzy}{-(\globyz*\globxx-\globyx*\globxz)/\mydet}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myzz}{(\globyy*\globxx-\globyx*\globxy)/\mydet} 
\tikzset{z={(\myzx,\myzy,\myzz)}}  
%\typeout{(\myxx,\myxy,\myxz),(\myyx,\myyy,\myyz),(\myzx,\myzy,\myzz)}
}}
\begin{document}
This is an attempt to provide some sort of an answer. Let's start by recalling
what Ti\emph{k}Z can do. Together with \texttt{tikz-3dplot} it allows you to
draw vectors in 3d. \texttt{tikz-3dplot} has the virtue of providing us with
proections of objects described by 3d orthogonal coordinate systems, see
figure~\ref{fig:3d1}.

Generally, regardless of whether or not we use \texttt{tikz-3dplot}, we can
install arbitrary coordinate systems with e.g. 
\begin{quote}
\texttt{\textbackslash
begin\{scope\}[x=\{($x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$)\},y=\{($y_1$,$y_2$,$y_3$)\},z=\{($z_1$,$z_2$,$z_3$)\}]}
\end{quote}
In this answer, we keep track of these transformations in order to be able to
invert them. Therefore, coordinate transformations now proceed in two steps:
\begin{enumerate}
 \item We define the vectors e.g.\ with
 \begin{quote}
\texttt{\textbackslash
begin\{scope\}[define x=\{($x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$)\},\dots]}
\end{quote}
 where the omission stands for analogous expressions for \texttt{y} and
 \texttt{z}.
 \item Then we can install a coordinate system simply with the key
 \texttt{install trafo}, see the red vectors in figure~\ref{fig:3d1}. (The red
 vectors got rescaled because your vectors have largish entries.)
 \item  And, this is the potentially new point here, we can install the inverse
 transformation with the \texttt{install inverse trafo} key. This is illustrated
 by the blue vectors in figure~\ref{fig:3d2}. (Note that if the
 vectors do not span the full 3d space, the determinant vanishes. However, at
 present there is no real error handler at work. 
\end{enumerate}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110} % sets the view angles, see the tik-3dplot manual for details 
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[pos=1.1]{$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[pos=1.1]{$y$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[pos=1.1]{$z$};
\begin{scope}[define x={(1,1,1)},define y={(1,4,5)},define z={(3,4,7)},
install trafo]
\begin{scope}[red,scale=1/25]
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[pos=1.1]{$x'$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[pos=1.1]{$y'$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[pos=1.1]{$z'$};
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Vectors in 3d and non--orthogonal basis vectors (red).}
\label{fig:3d1}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[pos=1.1]{$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[pos=1.1]{$y$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[pos=1.1]{$z$};
\begin{scope}[define x={(1,1,1)},define y={(1,4,5)},define z={(3,4,7)},
install inverse trafo,blue]
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[pos=1.1]{$x'$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[pos=1.1]{$y'$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[pos=1.1]{$z'$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Vectors in 3d and non--orthogonal basis vectors (blue).}
\label{fig:3d2}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\caption{Non--orthogonal 3d coordinate systems.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was more looking for something like implementation of PCA and rendering of its results (alike using https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-3/tb105fuster.pdf ) yet I havent found one yet...

Comment: @DuckQueen Thanks for the link! As far as I can see, it allows you to do some computations (including 3x3 matrix inversion, which I didn't know). Could you perhaps add a sketch of what you want to achieve to your question? (As it is tagged `tikz-pgf`, I am under the impression that you want to draw something related to these vectors. Or is that wrong?)